# How to write sql query for the following tables

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a table name as "invoice" which consists of column name "CId"

[image]

I have another table name as invoiceclient_details which consists of column name "CId"

So now my question is "what query should i write so that i will get the data of greater "CId" i.e. rows of data which consists of greater "CID"

I have tried like this

```
SELECT
invoiceclient_details.OrganizationName,
invoiceclient_details.InvoiceNo,
invoiceclient_details.InvoiceDate,
invoiceclient_details.DeliveryNote,
invoiceclient_details.TermsofPayment,
invoiceclient_details.EsugamNo,
invoiceclient_details.OrganizationName,
invoiceclient_details.BuyerOrderNo,
invoiceclient_details.BuyDate,
invoiceclient_details.DispatchDocumentNo,
invoiceclient_details.Dated,
invoiceclient_details.DispatchThrough,
invoiceclient_details.Destination,
invoiceclient_details.TermsofDelivery,
invoiceclient_details.BuyerTin,
invoice.id,
invoice.DescriptionOfGoods,
invoice.Quantity,
invoice.PerUnitPrice,
invoice.TotalPrice,
invoice.VAT14,
invoice.VAT5,
invoice.ServiceTax,
invoice.CST
FROM invoiceclient_details,invoice
WHERE MAX(invoiceclient_details.CId) = MAX(invoice.CId);
```

But it is showing an error like

> "misusage of group function"

Comment: could you please provide a sample output you're looking for? anyway sounds like you just need a inner join

Comment: For example, i need to print the data of table-1 i.e, invoice(CId=4) and table-2 i.e, invoiceclient_details(CId=4) then the query should be??

Comment: as suggested in the answer, you just need a inner join... yoy may also want to add a where clause using a parameter (first you need to create it in iReport)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * 
from invoice,invoiceclient_details 
where 
invoice.CId in (Select max(invoiceclient_details.CId) from invoiceclient_details) 
and 
invoiceclient_details.CId in (Select max(invoiceclient_details.CId) from invoiceclient_details)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `INNER JOIN` to join the tables on the `CId`.

```
SELECT *
FROM invoice i
INNER JOIN invoiceclient_details icd ON i.CId = icd.CId
```

Comment: its printing all the data i.e, CId=1 and CId=2 and CId=4 from "invoice" table. But i want CId=4 from both "invoice" and "invoiceclient_details"

Comment: WHERE i.CId = 4;... or WHERE i.CId = (Select max(Cid) FROM invoiceclient_details ),

Comment: @chitti oneterahertz, You better thank Matt.... next time avoid tagging jasper report if its only about sql... Have fun.... (I removed your tag ; )

Comment: yeah i added jasper report unnecessarily.sorry for that. Thank you @Matt for helping me